# How to prove $A^†A=I$

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm never really sure how to prove this formula.
The Moore-Penrose inverse, or so-called pseudoinverse, is defined as
$$A^{\dagger}=\left(A^* A\right)^{-1} A^*$$
simply shows that $A^{\dagger}A=I$ if $A^TA$ is invertible.

At first, I tried to make both sides of the equation have $A$:
$$A^{\dagger}A=\left(A^* A\right)^{-1} A^*A$$

but $A$ is not necessarily invertible, so this doesn't seem to work.

What can I do? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried just writing down $A^\dagger A$, expanding the definitions and trying to simplify?

Comment: If $A^TA$ is not invertible, then what is $A^\dagger$?

Comment: The formula in display mode is valid if $A$ is injective.

Comment: For surjective $A$, one would have $AA^+=E$, instead. The general case for obtaining $A^+$, on the other hand, is quite involved.